# AWS IAM find a role that has a specific policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Kind of a newbie still with AWS IAM. Is there a way to find all of the available *Roles* in a given account that have a specific *Policy* attached?  i.e. if you only know the Policy, and you don't know the roles it's attached to, how do you find all of the roles that a given policy is attached?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using API/CLI, you can make use of the [ListEntitiesForPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListEntitiesForPolicy.html) call. A CLI command that you could run would be:

```
$ aws iam list-entities-for-policy --policy-arn <arn_of_policy> --entity-filter Role
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Identity and Access Management (IAM) -> Policies -> Choose a spesific policy. The info you are looking for is under `Policy usage` tab.